# Vue component load only when i open console mode on browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, jvectormap

I've created this component in vue js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    Vue.component('mappa', {
      mounted() { 
        console.log("redy;");
       this.initMap();
      },

      template: `
        <div class="map-wrapper">
          <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
        </div>
      `,
       methods: {
            initMap() {
                $('#map').vectorMap({
                  map: 'world_mill',
                  backgroundColor: "transparent",
                  zoomOnScroll: false,
                  zoomButtons: false,
                  regionStyle: {
                    initial: {
                      fill: '#128da7'
                    }
                  }
                });
            },


              }
    })

}
```

and I call the template in html

```
<mappa></mappa>
```

But the map load only after I press f12 on my chrome browser or when I close it if I load the page with the console opened.

It happens only if I load the map inside mu vue app. in component but also if I use pure javascript. Instead it loads perfectly if I put the map outside my main vue app.

> console.log("redy;")

instead always log

I'm not using node, Just a SPA.

How possible? Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: I wouldn't define the component within the _document ready_ event handler, that's probably too late

Comment: The problem occurs also whit component outside the document.ready. My new Vue (main) is inside the document.ready ot it will not work otherwise.

Comment: The problem in html seems to be "<svg width="0" height="0">" and  "<g transform="scale(0)" in default set all to 0. 
Also I'm getting this error: 
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "scale(NaN) translate(N…".
jvm.SVGCanvasElement.applyTransformParams @ jquery-jvectormap-2.0.5.min.js:1"
I'm still searching a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple (assuming my suspicion is correct)

When you are executing the `mounted` lifecycle hook, the expectation is that the *component* has mounted, but it doesn't guarantee that the children have all mounted too.

There is a simple way to get around that though, and that is to use the `$nextTick` function.

example:

```js
Vue.component("mappa", {
  mounted() {
    console.log("redy;");
    this.$nextTick(this.initMap);
  },
  template: `
    <div class="map-wrapper">
      <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      $("#map").vectorMap({
        map: "world_mill",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        zoomButtons: false,
        regionStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: "#128da7"
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

references:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick